# C++ 17 | Debugging Output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

What I want to do, is when I run a program in debug mode, I want it to cout to the console or even possibly the game window what it's doing, like for an example, `GameWindow::Initialized(args...)`, and I want that to run throughout the program until it ends. Also, if I get the functions for that (I believe there is some on google), instead of checking if it's in debug mode: 'if (_Debug) {}', for each time I want to call the function that cout's to the screen, is there a way I can just do the debug checking once and have it done?

My guess is that I could create a thread and have it check if it's in debug mode, I could use a function that checks live what the game is doing and have that run continuously. I need to do more on threading because I've not done it in a while.

Thanks for reading, if you could help me or even agree that my method would work, I'd highly appreciate that :)

Comment: Sounds like what a tracepoint is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I've just decided to do something really simple, so all I done is define a log function which takes in a parameter and then output that to the console, if debug mode is on, otherwise, all I done is do an #else and then do the same thing, but I didn't output it. So just #define LOG(x) /* Nothing Else */ ->This is for release

Answer (score 0):

Normally you `#define NDEBUG` if you are not in debug mode. So you can

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    cout << "test\n";
#endif
```

Comment: I personally use
<code>
#ifdef _DEBUG
    bool Debug = 1
#endif
</code>

- I've never asked a question on SOF so I don't know how to use the Syntax Highlighting.

Comment: So if you already have a working solution, what is your question?

Comment: Well, as I said, say if I were to print many things in separate functions if it's running in debug mode, instead of using an if statement or #ifdef, I could use a function to cout everything that's happening, like Game::Initialize(), Game::Quit(), etc...

I'm wondering if that would work, but I need to do some research on how to actually get what's happening.

Comment: You can write a central logging function and let this function decide if to log or not (with the `#ifdef`). Depending on what you want to log that might be a bit challenging (different arguments, but you surely want type safety). Or you could use a macro that hides the `#ifdef` logic. Different approaches with different benefits and caveats.